# Sending a password protected file over exchangelib

Tags: python, encryption, zip, exchangelib

I need to send a daily email with an excel file that must be password protected. I have been using `exchangelib` for my email needs so far. I would prefer not to switch / add a different library if possible.

sending emails with attachments has not been a problem, just figuring out how to password protect and send. I thought I got close with this solution, compressing and sending as a zip file, but can't seem to attach the zip archive, just the contents.

```
from exchangelib import Message, Account, FileAttachment
from pyminizip import compress

m = Message(
    account=Account(...),
    subject="Some Subject",
    to_recipients=['somebody@theiremail.com']
)

xl_file_path = 'temp.xlsx'
zip_archive = 'secure.zip'
password = 'HomerSimpson'

compress(
    xl_file_path,
    None,
    zip_archive,
    password,
    5
)

with open(zip_archive, 'wb') as f:
    zip_archive_content = f.read()

m.attach(FileAttachment(
    name=zip_archive,
    content=zip_archive_content
))

m.send()
```

When this gets sent, it is actually sending the original excel file. To prove it to myself, when the attachment is downloaded and given a ".xlsx" extension instead of ".zip" it opens right up.

I am aware that there is password protection in the `openpyxl` library, but that is a weak protection (does not encrypt). My understanding is that the `compress` function is actually encrypting the data - which is what I want.

My hope is that I am just missing something simple about sending a zip archive as an attachment, but would accept other alternatives to password protecting the file or if there really is no other option - switching to a different method for sending emails.

Thoughts?

**Edit**

I did verify that the `secure.zip` archive is in the same directory as this script and does work correctly when opening manually (i.e. it contains my Excel file and is password protected).

Comment: Can you see the file `secure.zip` in your filesystem, in the same directory as the Python script? Is it compressed and protected?

Comment: If you have checked that `content` actually contains zipped data, and `name` actually contains the zip filename, then it's possible that your client (Outlook, I presume) automatically unzips the attachment. Finally, you may need to set the `content_type` attribute on the attachment to something that is relevant for zipped files.

Comment: `secure.zip` is in my filesystem and is protected.

Comment: I do not think opening a zip archive works the way I have done it here. If I take that `zip_archive_content` and re-save in my script with `open('new_archive.zip', 'rb') as f` then `f.write(zip_archive_content)`, I find that the 'new_archive.zip' file is actually an excel file and I rename it with a `.xlsx` extension I can open it directly in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Erik in the comments. Setting `content_type='application/zip'` in the `FileAttachment` is what I needed.

```
m.attach(FileAttachment(
    name=name,
    content=content,
    content_type='application/zip',
))
```